# Sparse matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-solver, sparse-matrix

I have the impedance matrix $Y$, formulated from an electrical network by augmented nodal analysis. The matrix $Y$ is shown as an image to illustrate its feature visually, where all the white blocks are zero.

[image]

What could be the best possible way to inverse such matrix which is required to solve the linear equation in the form $Yx=b$? Furthermore, in each iteration of the network solution, only the first $8\times 8$ elements get new values. All other elements remain as is. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to solve la linear equation, not invert a matrix, in which case, don;t invert the matrix.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a method of solving the linear equation that will be computationally efficient in this case. Note that the matrix is not a "positive definite" as it fails Cholesky decomposition. Thanks

Comment: how large is your matrix $Y$? depending on the overall size of $Y$ wrt to the $8\times 8$ changing block, there might be several alternatives to consider.

Comment: As shown in figure Y is a 19x19 matrix where the first 8X8 is changing in every iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a matrix that small, you're probably not going to do better than using dense methods.

I wrote up a quick test in C++ for an 18x18 matrix with your sparse structure and randomly generated values and compared a sparse factorization (via [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl)'s [PARDISO](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-intel-mkl-pardiso-parallel-direct-sparse-solver-interface)) and the same dense factorization via Intel MKL's [DGETRF](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-getrf).

- For the dense factorizations, any memory allocations aren't included in the timing.
- For the sparse factorizations, if I include in the timing the symbolic factorization (Phase 1 in PARDISO), which contains a lot of memory allocations, I find that the dense factorization is about **10x-20x** faster than the sparse factorization.
- For the sparse factorizations, if I don't include the symbolic factorization in the timing, since it could conceivably be calculated once before the numerical factorization, I find that the dense factorization is about **1.5x-3x** faster.

Of course your results may vary based on hardware, software, phases of the moon, etc, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what ballpark you're in.